# Put specific cell into the stamps.com desktop application

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I'm trying to use UIAutomation with Excel VBA to take an address from a specific cell and put it into the stamps.com desktop application and then auto print.

I looked at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pYanOx3tcE, which is the only thing I found online, but can't figure out how to use that.
I know web automation with Excel. Is there a similar, simple way to do this?

EDIT: I figured out how to get the values into the appropriate text boxes, but have one issue.
When I paste the address in the address box it does not initialize unless the enter key is pressed.
A `TextChangeEvent` might need to be fired. How would I do that?

```
Sub UIA_Address()
Dim oInvokePattern As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationInvokePattern
Dim oPattern As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationLegacyIAccessiblePattern

Set MyElement1 = WalkEnabledElements(oAutomation.GetRootElement, "Stamps.com")

Set MyElement2 = MyElement1.FindFirst(TreeScope_Children, PropCondition(oAutomation, "AfxWnd120", "ClsName"))

Set MyElement1 = MyElement2.FindFirst(TreeScope_Children, PropCondition(oAutomation, "SdcDlgViewWnd", "ClsName"))

Set MyElement2 = MyElement1.FindFirst(TreeScope_Children, PropCondition(oAutomation, "1470", "AutoID"))

LR = Range("C:C").Find("").Row + 14
'Set Print Message
Set MyElement1 = MyElement2.FindFirst(TreeScope_Children, PropCondition(oAutomation, "20002", "AutoID"))
Set oPattern = MyElement1.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_LegacyIAccessiblePatternId)
oPattern.SetValue (Range("D" & LR) & vbNewLine & Range("D" & LR + 1) & vbNewLine & Range("D" & LR + 2) & Range("D" & LR + 3))
End Sub

Function PropCondition(UIAutomation As CUIAutomation, Requirement As String, IDType As String) As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationCondition
    Select Case IDType
        Case "Name"
            Set PropCondition = UIAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIAutomationClient.UIA_NamePropertyId, Requirement)
        Case "AutoID"
            Set PropCondition = UIAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIAutomationClient.UIA_AutomationIdPropertyId, Requirement)
        Case "ClsName"
            Set PropCondition = UIAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIAutomationClient.UIA_ClassNamePropertyId, Requirement)
        Case "LoczCon"
            Set PropCondition = UIAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIAutomationClient.UIA_LocalizedControlTypePropertyId, Requirement)
    End Select
End Function

Function WalkEnabledElements(element As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement, strWindowName As String) As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement
    Dim walker As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationTreeWalker

    Set walker = oAutomation.ControlViewWalker
    Set element = walker.GetFirstChildElement(element)

    Do While Not element Is Nothing
        Debug.Print element.CurrentName

        If InStr(1, element.CurrentName, strWindowName) > 0 Then
            Set WalkEnabledElements = element
            Exit Function
        End If

        Set element = walker.GetNextSiblingElement(element)
    Loop
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

VBA is not good for UI automation. If you know a bit of programming, please try Python's pyautogui. Its very easy.

Link - [pyautoui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)